# C: Pointer to an array of structs inside a struct within a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am pretty new to C. I created a struct and an array of structs to store data and passed each of them to my functions:

```
int dosomething(struct s1 *struct1, struct s2 *struct2);

struct S1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct S2 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};


int main()
{
    int n = 200;
    struct S1 s1;
    struct S2 *s2 = malloc(n * sizeof(struct S2));

    dosomething(&s1, &s2[0])

    return 0;
}

int dosomething(struct S1 *s1, struct S2 *s2)
{
    s1->a = 1;
    s1->b = 2;
    s1->c = 3;

    s2[0].x = 1.1;
    s2[1].x = 1.123233;
    ...

    return 1;
}
```

This got pretty annoying over time, so I decided to put them together.
Now I am doing this

```
struct S1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    struct S2 *s2;
};

struct S2 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};


int main()
{
    int n = 200;
    struct S1 s1;
    struct S2 *s2 = malloc(n * sizeof(struct S2));
    s1.s2 = s2;

    dosomething(&s1)

    return 0;
}


int dosomething(struct S1 *s1)
{
    s1->a = 1;
    s1->b = 2;
    s1->c = 3;

    s1->s2[0].x = 1.1;
    s1->s2[1].x = 1.123233;
    ...

    // OR

    struct S2 *s2 = s1->s2;
    s2[0].x = 1.1;
    s2[1].x = 1.123233;
    ...
}
```

Now, the thing is:
I read a lot about pointers to structs, to arrays, to arrays of structs and so on, but I am still not sure, if what I am doing here is correct.
[C: pointer to array of pointers to structures (allocation/deallocation issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397728/c-pointer-to-array-of-pointers-to-structures-allocation-deallocation-issues),
[c pointer to array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201607/c-pointer-to-array-of-structs),
[How to declare pointer to array of structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477682/how-to-declare-pointer-to-array-of-structs-in-c),
[Pointer to array of struct in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991700/pointer-to-array-of-struct-in-function).
My project is growing to a size where I just don't want to make it worse by trying to make it better.

Do I need to make an array of pointers to the s2.s1[x]?

Do I need to tell the one pointer (struct S2 *s2 = s1->s2) how much elements s2 has?

Are there any pitfalls or could something go wrong?

Comment: Does your compiler show any warnings? About implicit declaration of `main()`?

Comment: What you have done seems fine from language point of view (it has no errors and has correct functionality), But design wise it can be made better

Comment: Where is `n` defined?

Comment: You need the number of elements that the pointer holds.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY True, it could be another structure member.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi It is just a minimal example I derived from my Situation. In my original code there is no such warning. Why do you think it could be?

Comment: @Groo Well, in this example nowhere. I will correct that.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya How could a better design look like?

Comment: @dimplemind: it would be better to 1. post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and 2. use your **actual** code (which is a requirement for Code Review anyway). Using obfuscated names like S1 and S2 makes code reviewing and reasonable suggestions pretty much impossible.

Comment: @Groo I understand your intention. But for me it was just a pretty basic difficulty without a big connection to the actual project. If I would post it on Code Review, I'd had to post 1300 rows of code (well, not all are relevant). But I didn't know Code Review exists, so I will have a look there.

Comment: It doesn't have to be your entire program, just don't use hypothetical identifiers and be clear about *what* the program is supposed to do. You can remove the parts of `struct`s if it doesn't change the meaning. `do_stuff(&s1);` is bad, `calculate_taxes(&person);` is good.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You mean it shoulde be: `struct S2 (*s2)[n] = s1->s2;` ?

Comment: E.g `int c; struct S2 *s2;` --> `int c; size_t n; struct S2 *s2;` ... `struct S2 *s2 = malloc(n * sizeof(struct S2));
    s1.s2 = s2; s1.n = n;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it, it is a matter of whether or not it fits your requirements and that it is a good design choice in the long term.

Also, you can probably do

```
s1.s2 = malloc(sizeof *s1.s2);
if (s1.s2 == NULL)
    error_handler(); // do not use s1.s2 after this
dosomething(&s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing a struct, pointer or an array inside another struct is called *composition*. You should be placing the `S2` array inside the `S1` struct **if it belongs there**.

For example, a `Point` is a pair of `(x, y)` coordinates, so it's obvious it should be composed of two `int`s, i.e.:

```
void do_stuff(struct Point pt);
```

Is better than:

```
void do_stuff(int x, int y);
```

**But never do this just because you want to spare some typing. Do it if `S2` fits inside `S1`.** If "there is no `S1` without `S2`" in your program, then it makes sense.

So if these two structs **don't** belong together, but you find yourself passing the same sequence of parameters to multiple functions, then you can use a variant of OOP refactoring technique called ["introduce parameter object"](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object). I.e. instead of doing this:

```
do_stuff(&s1, &s2, &s3);
```

You can create a new struct whose no other purpose is but to be composed of these parameters:

```
struct StuffParameters {
    struct S1 * s1;
    struct S2 * s2;
    struct S3 * s3;
};
```

And then you can pass it to multiple "similar" functions:

```
struct StuffParameters parameters = { &s1, &s2, &s3 };

do_stuff(&parameters);
do_some_other_stuff(&parameters);
yet_another_function(&parameters);
```

Comment: Well, at the beginning I didn't know how to put the structs together and I wanted to have the code run. But they belong together. The "introduce parameter object" looks quite interesting. I have to remember that.

Comment: @dimplemind: the idea with "introduce parameter object" (although C is not object-oriented) is a bit cooler than it first seems, as it allows you to extract all functions relevant to this set of parameters in a separate "module", while still leaving these structs logically separate for the functions where this makes sense. In C++, all these functions working on this new "parameter object" would be members of its separate class. But again, it would be better if you posted an actual chunk of your code to clarify what these structs actually represent.

Comment: Today it is too late. I will leave in a minute. Maybe tomorrow I will post at least the relevant parts.